# Why's the linker not finding just a single (present) method in a library?

Tags: c++, linker-errors, ld

So I recently started using a library called libgambatte ([github](https://github.com/sinamas/gambatte)), everything was going just fine until the linker started complaining about an undefined reference for a method. What's really strange is that it find every other method for that object! Arguments' types are correct (I've copied them from the working program included with the library).

Here's the code:

**Make output**:

```
g++  -Wall -Wextra -g3 -I../libgambatte/include -I../common  -c -o test.o test.cpp
g++ test.o -L../libgambatte -lgambatte -lz -o test
test.o: In function `main':
<REDACTED>/src/test.cpp:12: undefined reference to `gambatte::GB::runFor(unsigned long*, long, unsigned long*, unsigned long&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:9: recipe for target 'test' failed
make: *** [test] Error 1
```

**Makefile**:

```
CPPFLAGS=-Wall -Wextra -g3 -I../libgambatte/include -I../common
LDFLAGS=-L../libgambatte -lgambatte -lz

.PHONY=all clean

all: test

test: test.o
    $(CXX) test.o $(LDFLAGS) -o test

clean:
    rm -f test.o test
```

**Output of `nm ../libgambatte/libgambatte.a | grep runFor`**:

```
0000000000007a20 T _ZN8gambatte3CPU6runForEm
0000000000000190 T _ZN8gambatte2GB6runForEPjlS1_Rm
                 U _ZN8gambatte3CPU6runForEm
```

**Source for `test.cpp`**:

```
#include <gambatte.h>

using namespace std;

int main(void){
    gambatte::uint_least32_t audiobuf[1234];
    gambatte::uint_least32_t framebuf[1234];
    size_t samples = 1234;
    unsigned gb_width = 160;
    gambatte::GB gb;

    gb.runFor(framebuf, gb_width, audiobuf, samples);

    return 0;
}
```

**`runFor` method declaration**:

```
std::ptrdiff_t runFor(gambatte::uint_least32_t *videoBuf, std::ptrdiff_t pitch,
                      gambatte::uint_least32_t *audioBuf, std::size_t &samples);
```

**Definition for `gambatte::uint_least32_t`**:

```
#ifdef HAVE_CSTDINT

#include <cstdint>

namespace gambatte {
    using std::uint_least32_t;
    using std::uint_least16_t;
}

#elif defined(HAVE_STDINT_H)

#include <stdint.h>

namespace gambatte {
    using ::uint_least32_t;
    using ::uint_least16_t;
}

#else

namespace gambatte {
#ifdef CHAR_LEAST_32
    typedef unsigned char uint_least32_t;
#elif defined(SHORT_LEAST_32)
    typedef unsigned short uint_least32_t;
#elif defined(INT_LEAST_32)
    typedef unsigned uint_least32_t;
#else
    typedef unsigned long uint_least32_t;
#endif

#ifdef CHAR_LEAST_16
    typedef unsigned char uint_least16_t;
#else
    typedef unsigned short uint_least16_t;
#endif
}
#endif
```

Sorry for the long code.

Comment: What happens if you explicitly use `unsigned long` instead of `uint_least32_t`?

Comment: @Jason nothing changes, I've just tried and everything stays the same..

Comment: Any recent updates to your gcc package? Are you sure that libgambatte is compiled with the same tool version? Does `std::ptrdiff_t gb_width` instead of `unsigned gb_width` make any difference?

Comment: @grek40 no recent updates, I use the same tool and the same library file to compile both the working program included in the library, and mine. Using `ptrdiff_t` makes no difference, I use `unsigned` because the working program uses the same type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the problem: as you can see in the definition of `gambatte::uint_least32_t`, the type definition is based on the presence of certain constants. My problem manifested because the library (and the included program) are compiled with `-DHAVE_STDINT_H` and therefore define `gambatte::uint_least32_t` as a different type, causing the linker to not find the correct signature; compiling with `-DHAVE_STDINT_H` solved the problem for me.